# Using Orthophotos - not multispectral - to generate Object-oriented image classification vectors?

Tags: qgis, vectorization, orthophoto

I'm using  QGIS version 2.14.3-Essen on a Macbook pro. I'm sort of new to this and feeling my way through this.

I have high-resolution Orthophotos officially sourced from local country in Sub-saharan Africa. These are already composite TIFFS and not multi-band.

I want to be able to visualise the different land coverage i.e agriculture, buidlings, forestry etc from these images, and to have this in a vector file format.

I'm not sure how to do this.

Exploring the web I came across Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin for QGIS. However I am not getting very far and I'm wondering is it because they are Flattened Tiffs and not multispectral? I keep getting errors when I try to draw the ROI's.